# GlobalSearch function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

its seems I cannot run global optimization functions (GlobalSearch,GlobalPenaltyFn);

The output is just a reproduction of input

In[] = GlobalSearch[(x - 1.3)^2 + (y - 1.5)^2, {-x + 1, -y + 1}, {x - 
   y}, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}, .000001, Starts -> 1]

Out[]= GlobalSearch[(-1.3 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2, {1 - x, 
  1 - y}, {x - y}, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}, 1.*10^-6, Starts -> 1]

Question:

are those functions at all integrated with mathematica 10, 11 or one has to upgrade to this?

thanks, Damir

Comment: It seems to be part of that commercial package: http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/globalopt/

Comment: is there a good compromise to this? Black box gradient-free optimization

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has built-in constrained minimization capabilities, e.g., [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)

```
sys = {(x - 13/10)^2 + (y - 3/2)^2, -x + 1 < 0, -y + 1 < 0, 
   x - y == 0};

min = Minimize[sys, {x, y}]

(* {1/50, {x -> 7/5, y -> 7/5}} *)
```

Verifying that constraints are satisfied,

```
Rest@sys /. min[[2]]

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Plotting,

```
Show[
 Plot3D[(x - 13/10)^2 + (y - 3/2)^2,
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{x, y, min[[1]]} /. min[[2]]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment; This is with a user-defined function. From here http://www.addlink.es/images/pdf/agdweb1187.pdf  Comparison shows that Minimize will break for a black-box function i.e. passing only a scalar for some input parameters.

Comment: @damir - The paper to which you linked is about 13 years old. `Minimize` has been updated since then. If you are having a specific problem with `Minimize` or related functions, I recommend that you post a question with the details.

Comment: @damir Use `NMinimize` for black-box functions.